# pyspark write to hive table in reduced/compressed number of small files

Tags: dataframe, hadoop, pyspark, hive, hdfs

I have a dataframe record updated everytime a process runs, that means i will have a dataframe of one row and 4 columns every time the process completes.
Then I will insert it into the hive table using dataframe write and in parquet format.
Because of one record at a time, I'm seeing so many small files in the table folder in hfds.

Could you please let me know how to reduce and write it to same file (parquet file) when I'm writing the data to the hive table??

```
hdfs location: user_id/employe_db/market_table/
from:
part-04498-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
part-04497-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
part-04496-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
part-04496-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
part-04450-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
part-04449-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet

to:
part-03049-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet
```

How to reduce the number of parquet files to fixed no# of less files and load/write the new data into the existing files??
part-04499-f33fc4b5-47d9-4d14-b37e-8f670cb2c53c-c000.snappy.parquet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before writing to **`HDFS`** you can **`repartition(1)`** so that you will create 1 file per execution.

```
df.repartition(1).write.parquet("<directory>")
```

**`Merging files:`**

**`Using Hive:`**

If you already have hive table on top of `user_id/employe_db/market_table/` directory then run insert overwrite by selecting same table.

```
spark.sql("insert overwrite table <db>.<tab_market> select * from <db>.<tab_market>")
```

--to create only one file then use order by

```
spark.sql("insert overwrite table <db>.<tab_market> select * from <db>.<tab_market> order by <column>")
```

You can run insert statements as is in Hive also.

(or)

**`Using Spark:`**

As a post ingestion process you can again **read the parquet files** from the directory then do repartition again and write to the directory.

```
df_src=spark.read.parquet("<directory>")
df_src.repartition(<number>).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("<directory>")
```

**`NOTE`**

- overwrite first deletes the directory, in case if job failed in between we may encounter data loss.
- Its best practice to take a backup of data into tmp directory then only overwrite

Comment: to use this answer,  first backup the data as suggested in note or else this will cause `FileNotFoundException` see this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61052681/4758823

Comment: Actually I'm not getting. The the reason why I'm trying this code is that in our HDFS namespace there is a retension that the no# of files in a particular directory doesn't exceed 10K no# of files, so when writing to that table path how can I make sure to have less number of parquet files???

Comment: Thanks @Shu. But, df.repartition(1).write.parquet("<directory>") - correct it will create a single file after repartitioning.
But, what about the files which are already in that hdfs folder. Multiple small files are getting increasing , that is the problem I'm facing. So you have any option how to resolve?

Comment: @SureshGudimetla, In the answer i have added ways to merge files in table  in **`Merging files:`** section. By using these ways you can merge the small files and create bigger files in HDFS.

Comment: @Shu Thanks, it worked. But, when I'm inserting new data - so **1.** I'm appending data to the existing table. **2.** As per your point I'm reading the data and overwriting to same table using repartiition(1) could see the same number of records.

Comment: @SureshGudimetla, Yes, you will same number of records. If you use `orderby` clause in your insert statement then `1` file going to be created in HDFS directory. If not hive will create files as per hive default params.

Comment: @Shu, I have tried the spark one which you have provided:
**df_src=spark.read.parquet("<directory>")
df_src.repartition(<number>).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("<directory>")**

Comment: Updated comment:  --- @Shu, I have tried the spark one which you have provided:
**df_src=spark.read.parquet("<directory>")
df_src.repartition(<number>).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("<directory>")**
So, I should order by on the partition column when I'm writing agian or on which column i need to do orderBy??

Comment: I have the issue as per my above comment, the data is not getting refreshed and I don't have anyother option. Even I tried insertInto() option at the time of write.

Comment: Will this impact size of the output file on disk?